# How to retrieve lib directory?

Tags: bash

How can I use bash to retrieve lib directory? For example: `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`?

*Edit*

I'm packaging an RPM which copies some files to `%{_libdir}`. So I'd like to know the path to lib directory… I can use `if [ -f "path-to-my-file" ]; then ...` but I wonder if there is a command line?

Comment: What do you mean by retrieving the lib directory? You can simply specify the path as you have done in the question

Comment: There isn't a single `lib` directory on a UNIX system, there are several ones. What do you intend to do with that directory once you "retrieve" it?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. My ISP is very sick at this moment. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

ldd - print shared library dependencies

```
$ ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbeecc000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fa9aa630000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa9aa428000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0x00007fa9aa220000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa9a9ebe000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa9a9cba000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa9aa868000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa9a9a9d000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0x00007fa9a9899000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
```

Will show you where the linker looks for libraries by default.